# Reversing time for a closed system of particles

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle, action, time-reversal-symmetry

For a closed system of particles, the lagrangian in classical mechanics is

$$L=\sum \frac{1}{2}mv_a^2 - U(\mathbf{r_1},\mathbf{r_2}, \cdots)$$

For an arbitrary position function $x(t)$, to see the progression of position values in the reverse chronological order (i.e., to reverse time), $x(-t)$ provides what we're looking for.

But since the lagrangian does not change when you change $t$ to $-t$, the extremal of the action remains the same, $x(t)$. But technically, shouldn't you get $x(-t)$ - because if you were not given the lagrangian and directly given $x(t)$, changing $t$ to $-t$ would give you $x(-t)$?

Comment: And the question is ... ???

Answer (score 1):

Comment to the post (v2): It is true that if $t\mapsto q(t)$ is a solution to the [Euler-Lagrange (EL) eqs.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation) 
for the action $$S[q]~=~\int_{t_i}^{t_f} \! dt  L(q^1,q^2,q^3, \ldots; (\dot{q}^1)^2,(\dot{q}^2)^2,(\dot{q}^3)^2, \ldots)$$ of a time-symmetric Lagrangian, then the time-reversed path $t\mapsto q(-t)$ would also be a solution to the EL eqs. In fact, there are infinitely many solutions to the EL eqs. However, recall that to have a well-posed [variational problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_action), one should also impose appropriate boundary conditions. And the boundary conditions may not be invariant under the [time-reversal symmetry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-symmetry), and hence able to distinguish a path from its time-reversed path.